# find occurrence of string starting with a value in R

Tags: r

Is there a function for printing the total number of values contained in the dataset beginning with (a value)?

consider this dataset of 4 version numbers,

```
df <- c("1.20", "3.1.20", "2.45", "1.10", "1.67.4.3", "5.200.1", "70.1.2.7")
```

I need to only print version numbers `1.x`.
My output would be:

```
1.20, 1.10, 1.67.4.3
```

(becasue these are version numbers **starting** with "1." I do not want to print `3.1.20` or `70.1.2.7` becasue they do not start with "1." eventhough they contain "1." as a substring

Answer (score 8):

```
df <- c("1.20", "3.1.20", "2.45", "1.10", "1.67.4.3", "5.200.1", "70.1.2.7")
grep("^1\\.", df, value = TRUE)
```

Comment: getting a charater(0) output

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `substring` inside brackets for subsetting:

```
df[substring(df, 1,2) == "1."]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
sum(substr(df, 1, 2) == "1.")
[1] 3
```

And for the values themselves:

```
df[substr(df, 1, 2) == "1."]
[1] "1.20"     "1.10"     "1.67.4.3"
```

Comment: I changed the code so that values such as "10." are not selected.

Answer (score 0):

```
df[df<"2"]
#[1] "1.20"     "1.10"     "1.67.4.3"
```

Depending on your dataset (e.g., if there are version numbers with a leading zero), you might need to expand this suggested solution by `df[df<"2" & df>="1"]`

The total number of values starting with a "1" can in this case be obtained with `length(df[df<"2"])` (or `length(df[df<"2" & df >="1"])` ).